# local network share error, no permission to create

Tags: samba, 20.04

Trying to share a folder from nautilus, I get the error message:

`'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Permission denied
You do not have permission to create a usershare. Ask your administrator to grant you permissions to create a share.`

User is added to sambashare group.

If I run nautilus as sudo, there is no error and sharing is enabled as expected. Is this a bug in latest Ubuntu or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not a member of the sambashare group so add yourself:

```
sudo gpasswd -a your-user-name sambashare
```

Then logout and log back in.

Comment: Question explicitly states that the user has been added to the sambashare group.

Comment: Then what are the permissions of that folder: `ls -dl /var/lib/samba/usershares`

Comment: Morbius1 I just tried again... and it worked as expected. I have not edited samba configuration in the mean time, I did try rebooting before etc... I am at a loss as to what was causing the issue. I suppose we consider this solved, for now.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, and as @kurja said, rebooting the machine seemed to work.

Here's what I did:

1. Add user to `sambashare` group. (Share still does not work.)
2. Log out, then log back in. (Share still does not work.)
3. Reboot the machine. (Share works.)

I imagine the logout/login step was not necessary, and instead there was something in the samba daemon that benefited from being restarted? It's possible that simply restarting the service would have fixed this, too.

But in any case, I want to affirm that this issue happened for me too, and a full reboot worked for me too, in case future people run into it.